# EMR on EKS : How to retrieve the master URL of the EMR cluster hosted on EKS to create spark context and run the job using the spark context

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, amazon-eks

In our application, we used to create single spark context using spark master and execute multiple  spark jobs using that. The same way we are looking with EMR on EKS also. Is there a way to perform it or it support this way or EMR is only available to submit jobs.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIU, EMR on EKS is not the same as EMR. When it created, it called "virtual cluster" - because it actually has nothing before you run a job. So, you can not retrieve master URL of EMR on EKS.
To run a job, it does not use YARN, like EMR, but it uses Kubernetes - same if you run a job which executes spark-submit to Kubernetes cluster, just it uses its own images for driver & executors. Also it has no HDFS.

If you want a "continuous" driver, make a job which will not finish if it has nothing to do, and send new data to it somehow.